# Obtaining the Green's function for a 2D Poisson equation ( in polar coordinates)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, differential-equations, greens-functions

I am trying to solve the following BVP within an annular region of radii $r_1$, and $r_2$ :
$$
\begin{cases}
\nabla^2u=f\\
u(r_1) = p\\ u(r_2) = q
\end{cases}
$$
If we define an auxiliary problem in terms of Green's function as
$$
\begin{cases}
\nabla^2G=\delta^2(r-r')\\ 
G(r_1) = 0 \\ 
G(r_2) = 0\\
\end{cases}
$$
We have the solution of u (as given by Green's identities as)
$$\DeclareMathOperator{\Dm}{\operatorname{d}\!}
u = \oint u  \frac{\partial G}{\partial n} \Dm S + \int Gf \Dm V   \tag{Eqn. A}
$$
How do I proceed to obtain the form of the Green's function ?

I understand that G for a finite boundary problem is done by superposition :

$G = G_{Freespace} + G_{Homogeneous}$

From my little searching I found that,
$G_{Freespace} = Aln(r-r')$, and
$G_{Homogeneous}=a_0 + a_nr^ncos(n\phi) + b_nr^nsin(n\phi)$

However, the expected solution ( from a paper) that I am seeking is of the form:

$2\pi G=H_0 (r_1,r_2) + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} H_n(r_1,r_2) cos(n(\phi_1 - \phi_2))$

The form of $H_0$ and $H_n$ are given in the attachment below.

[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPz88.png)

How do I obtain the solution above from the problem posed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"The Green's function" is a (very common) grammatical error that <strike>Clifford Truesdell</strike> I think once called an atrocity to the English language. (Complains a German... ;) ) But you're excused, the paper you cite does it too.^^
Edit: My brain has betrayed me, I thought to have read this in Truesdell's "An iditiot's fugitive essays on Science", but it's actually a footnote in Rohrlich's "Classical Charged Particles", Chap. 4-7. Full quote:

> The commonly used expressions "the Green's function" and "a Green's function" represent an atrocity to the English language. I doubt that those who use them ever refer to "a Shakespeare's sonnet".

More on-topic: You're halfway there! Usual technique is to use the free-space and homogeneous contributions you give (the latter is missing a sum!) and try to match the boundary conditions. Here you need to fulfill $G=0$ at $r_1$ and $r_2$. Have fun comparing coefficients and using trigonometric identities. I might have a closer look later myself.

Edit: Some more info to get into the solution process.
The solution of problems like this in cylindrical coordinates is a common problem, and you could have a look at J.D. Jackson: Classical Electrodynamics, Chapter 3.11; Panofsky&Phillips: Classical Electricity and Magnetism, Chapter 4-9f or W.A. Strauss: Partial Differential Equations, Chapter 10.2, for example.

To find the Green function as the sum of the free-space and homogeneous conribution, let's start with the free-space contribution:
It reads
$$
G_f\left(\vec{r},\vec{r}'\right) = - 2 \pi \ln\left(\frac{\left|\vec{r}-\vec{r}'\right|}{r_0}\right)
$$
with an arbitrary constant $r_0$ (if this arbitrariness weirds you out, have a look in Panofsky&Phillips, but it's not that important).
Now to express that in cylindrical coordinates with radius $r$/$r'$ and polar angle $\phi$/$\phi'$ ($r_1$, $r_2$ etc. in the paper, which in your notation are the constant inner and outer radii)
$$
G_f\left(\vec{r},\vec{r}'\right) = - 2 \pi \ln\left(\frac{\sqrt{r^2+\left(r'\right)^2-2rr'\cos\left(\phi-\phi'\right)}}{r_0}\right)
$$
by the law of cosines. But we need to do some work on this to obtain the form in the paper. J.D. Jackson might help you here a bit.

For the homogeneous part we use your ansatz. This stems from a separation ansatz (see the cited references) and contains the sine and cosine contributions (which are eigenfunctions of the second-derivative-operator on a circle) and powers of the radius $r$ with coefficients later to be matched to fullfill the radial part of the Poisson equation and the boundary conditions. Generally we could start off with something like
$$
G_h\left(\vec{r},\vec{r}'\right) = \sum_n r^n\left(a_n \sin\left(n\phi\right) + b_n \cos\left(n\phi\right)\right) \sum_m r'^m\left(a'_m \sin\left(m\phi'\right) + b'_m \cos\left(m\phi'\right)\right)\,,
$$
which looks bad, but can be simplified immediately by using symmetries of the problem.

Invariance under rotation tells us right away that the dependence on $\phi$ and $\phi'$ can only be a dependence on their difference, so we'd expect something like
$$
... \left(a_n \sin\left(n\left(\phi-\phi'\right)\right) + b_n \cos\left(n\left(\phi-\phi'\right)\right)\right)\,,
$$
but then further we can use that $G\left(\vec{r},\vec{r}'\right) = G\left(\vec{r}',\vec{r}\right)$ and we're only left with the cosines.
You see the solution in the paper come along, right? Still, way to go.

Comment: Thanks. What I did not understand is how $\phi_2$ came up in the homogeneous part. Some pointers towards the solution could really help me understand.

Comment: I'm curious, why would "Green's function" 
be a  grammatical error?

Comment: @lcv Not sure (maybe my calling it a grammatical error is actually an error^^), but I've added a reference.

Comment: Thank you very much @kricheli. That gives me some very good pointers to work on.

Comment: I get the rotational invariance part, but as we have $ r^n cos n(\phi_1) ...  r'^m cos n(\phi_2) $, how can we combine to $ cos (n(\phi_1-\phi_2)) $, as we have r and r' as prefactors ?

Comment: @kricheli thanks, very interesting. So what would be the rule then? It seems that Schrödinger's equation should be equally bad, or perhaps not?  Is the point that owning an equation is okay, but owning a function is awkward? Perhaps I can ask a separate question.

Comment: @Mechanician Within this large sum you can find terms with the same powers of $r$ and $r'$ whose constant prefactors you can require to be equal to be able to fulfill the invariance we're looking for by doing something like $\cos(x+y) = \cos x \cos y - \sin x \sin y$, I think.

Comment: @lcv No, there's nothing wrong with "ownership", you can happily talk about "Schrödinger's equation" (or "Green's function") or "the Schrödinger equation" ("the Green function"), but "the Schrödinger's equation" is weird at least, maybe an actual error. If you open a question for that, post me a reference please, I'd be very interested.

Comment: @kricheli Not surprisingly there are some posts on the matter. See e.g., https://www.nature.com/articles/nphys411 or  https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/140529/greens-functions-or-green-functions . However none of those posts provide a definite answer.